# Confusion regarding enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I need help to understand `enable_shared_from_this`. I am bit confused about the use of `enable_shared_from_this`. 
To put in a correct way, let's consider one example copied from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Good: std::enable_shared_from_this<Good>
{
    std::shared_ptr<Good> getptr() {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};

struct Bad
{
    std::shared_ptr<Bad> getptr() {
        return std::shared_ptr<Bad>(this);
    }
    ~Bad() { std::cout << "Bad::~Bad() called\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    // Good: the two shared_ptr's share the same object
    std::shared_ptr<Good> gp1(new Good);
    std::shared_ptr<Good> gp2 = gp1->getptr();
    std::cout << "gp2.use_count() = " << gp2.use_count() << '\n';

    // Bad, each shared_ptr thinks it's the only owner of the object
    std::shared_ptr<Bad> bp1(new Bad);
    std::shared_ptr<Bad> bp2 = bp1->getptr();
    std::cout << "bp2.use_count() = " << bp2.use_count() << '\n';
} // UB: double-delete of Bad
```

In the above example

- we are calling `getptr()` from `gp1` which is a `shared_ptr`.

> ```
> std::shared_ptr<Good> gp2 = gp1->getptr();
> ```

- I think same thing we can achieve, if we do

> ```
> std::shared_ptr<Good> gp2 = gp1;
> ```

- There is a restriction I found is, we can't call getptr() from a
  normal object. It must be a shared_ptr.

Ex:

> ```
>  Good gp; gp.getptr(); // throws std::bad_weak_ptr 
>  Good *gp1 = new Good(); gp1->getptr();// throws std::bad_weak_ptr
> ```

My doubt is, when we already have `shared_ptr`, then we can also directly assigned to another `shared_ptr`. like `std::shared_ptr<Good> gp2 = gp1;`.

Then what is the need of `enable_shared_from_this` ?

Comment: For functions which takes `T&`(instead of `shared_ptr<T>`), and retrieve the `shared_ptr` afterward.

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42, I got your point.  when we have the object in a reference variable then from there we can get a `shared_ptr`, and this is possible by using `enable_shared_ptr`. Thanks alot .

Comment: Using enabled_shared_from_this is not a good design choice. Basically, class should not concern itself with it's own management. In a good design class can exist in multiple forms - it can be managed by a shared pointer, a unique pointer, a raw pointer and have automatic instances as well.

Answer (score 0):

A more common usage of shared_from_this() would be to provide a `shared_ptr` of the calling class to a function being called.  So if you need to provide a `shared_ptr` instance to a function, and you are sure that the class you are calling from is stored as a `shared_ptr`, then you can use `shared_from_this()`.  Pseudo-code example based on the one you referenced:

```
struct Good: std::enable_shared_from_this<Good>
{
    std::shared_ptr<Good> call_function() {
        Foo foo;
        foo.use_my_shared_ptr(shared_from_this());
    }
};
```

`Foo` here is just a class that need a shared_ptr to `Good`.